# Pairs probability in Poker

Tags: python

first time using this platform so hope I'm doing it the right way. I'm currently in high school and we have this project with this description: *Calculate the probability that when you deal 5 cards (without repeating cards) of poker you have two pairs*. I have already done the programming with some notes I took from class for the five cards:

```
import random

def generatedeck():
    deck = []
    for i in range(1,14):
        deck.extend([i]*4)
    return deck

def main():
    seed = int(input())
    random.seed(seed)
    for e in range(1000):
        deck = generatedeck()
        hand = []
    
        for i in range(5): 
            pos = random.randint(0,len(deck)-1) 
            card = deck.pop(pos) 
            hand.append(card) 

    print(hand)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

The thing is, I really don't know how to proceed to calculate the probability.

We do have some notes/examples for this homework.

- For example if your hand is:
  1,1,2,3,3 (there's a pair of 1 and a pair of 3) [The event is fulfilled]
  3,Q,3,3,3 (poker) [not fulfilled]
- The simulation needs to run 1000 times
- Simulation examples:
  (Input: 0, Output: 0.055)
  (Input: 11, Output: 0.047)
  (Input: 42, Output: 0.046)

Let me know what you think of the code in general, and if you think there is a better way to have the cards dealt. Thank you in advance for all your help!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637750/probability-of-getting-two-pair-in-poker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just like to preface that this answer is to get the experimental probability of a two pair occurring.

How I have fixed it is that after the five card hand is dealt, I loop through the hand and use list.count to return how many of those cards are in a deck. I check if that number is equal to two. This means that there is one pair. Then inside the if statement that find the first pair, I loop through the array again and find if there is a pair that is not equal to the first pair. If this is true, meaning that there is a two pair in that hand, I add to a variable that keeps track of how many two pairs there has been in 1000 iterations. After iterating through 1000 times I divide the number of two pairs by 1000 and then the experimental probability is reached. The code looks as follows:

```py
import random

def generatedeck():
    deck = []
    for i in range(1,14):
        deck.extend([i]*4)
    return deck

def main():
    seed = int(input("Enter a seed for Random: "))
    random.seed(seed)
    
    NumTwoPairs = 0
    num = 0
    for e in range(1000):
        deck = generatedeck()
        hand = []
    
        for i in range(5): 
            pos = random.randint(0,len(deck)-1) 
            card = deck.pop(pos) 
            hand.append(card)
        
        for elem in hand: #checking for the two pair
            if hand.count(elem) == 2:
                for el in hand:
                    if hand.count(el) == 2 and el != elem:
                        NumTwoPairs += 1
                        #print(hand)
                        break
                break
    
    return NumTwoPairs
    #print(hand)

print(main()/1000)
```

For the seed of `1` the returned output is
`0.049`

Comment: Thank you so much! Made it so much clearer. I ended up finding a way to do it but used set(), a function i hadn't used before.

Comment: Thats amazing, I quickly looked into the set() function and it seems that it might be more efficient than my solution that practically brute forces the answer. Although my answer might be good just to look at to try and understand the logic used, which might help later on in your coding journey.